# Format string with variadic arguments

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I have extension for String

```
func localized(table: String? = nil, bundle: Bundle = .main, args: CVarArg...) -> String {
  return String(
    format: NSLocalizedString(
      self,
      tableName: table,
      bundle: bundle,
      value: self,
      comment: ""
    ),
    args
  )
}
```

Localizable.strings file:

```
"%d seconds ago" = "%d seconds ago";
```

Usage:

```
print("%d seconds ago".localized(args: 5))
print(String.localizedStringWithFormat("%d seconds ago", 5))
```

And result:

```
<some_random_number_here> seconds ago.
5 seconds ago.
```

Can someone explain me what do I do wrong?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`String` has  two similar initializers:

```
init(format: String, _ arguments: CVarArg...)
init(format: String, arguments: [CVarArg])
```

The first one takes a varying number of arguments, the second one
an array with all arguments:

```
print(String(format: "x=%d, y=%d", 1, 2))
print(String(format: "x=%d, y=%d", arguments: [1, 2]))
```

In your `localized` method, `args: CVarArg...` is a *variadic parameter*
and those are made available within the functions body as an *array*
of the appropriated type, in this case `[CVarArg]`.
Therefore it must be passed to `String(format: arguments:)`:

```
func localized(table: String? = nil, bundle: Bundle = .main, args: CVarArg...) -> String {
  return String(
    format: NSLocalizedString(
      self,
      tableName: table,
      bundle: bundle,
      value: self,
      comment: ""
    ),
    arguments: args   // <--- HERE
  )
}
```

See also "Variadic Parameters" in the ["Functions"](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html) chapter of the
Swift reference.

Comment: That was really helpful. What about String.localizedStringWithFormat ? I realised there is no way to call it with an array. I'm in an Extension too.

Comment: @Mijail: Unfortunately, there seems to be no String.localizedStringWithFormat variant taking a [CVarArg] argument.

Comment: What Martin said took me a day to discover, there shouldn't be such different ways to do the same thing, because I was looking for an answer in the wrong place.

Comment: While your explanation of Vardics is right, there is a function which works with localized Strings and Lists: `String.init(format: String, locale: Any?, arguments: CVaListPointer)`. Calling it with `locale: Locale.current` is the same as using `.localizedStringWithFormat`. From the Apple docs: This method is meant to be called from within a variadic function, where the argument list will be available. On https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1408481-localizedstringwithformat.

Comment: that's the accepted answer, but it's weird that it's not working. error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x5)

Comment: @RajaSaad: I am fairly sure that I tested the code. But if the types of the argument do not match the format specifiers then it can crash.

Comment: thanks @MartinR, that's what exactly caused the crash.